# NUMPY TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'SingleBlockManager'

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, interpolation

I have some data x1,y1,z1  . In which i want to do interpolation of new points . 
I have some nan values in z1 , so i masked those nan value but after doing masking of z1 nan value i am getting Error while doing interpolation .

**1- How to solve  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'SingleBlockManager' ?
2- In this code i am doing interpolation using ISD and values are not so correct Is there any other Interpolation technique in which i can get correct interpolation values , i tried doing Linerinterpolation & Cubicinterpolation in which in some values i was getting NaN values as interpolation values**

```
import numpy as np


x1=[86.092069,86.092058,86.092044,86.092027,86.092013]

y1=[19.861997,19.857362,19.850790,19.843075,19.836572]

parms1=[86.89519676343816, 86.89849352687632, 86.90179029031448, 86.99599676343816, 86.99929352687631]
parms2=[21.31073049334863, 21.307660986697257, 21.304591480045886, 21.416630493348627, 21.413560986697256]

req_elevation=[np.nan, -0.01799242 ,np.nan, -0.01757328, -0.01739314]
req_elevation = np.ma.masked_invalid(req_elevation, np.nan)
print('req_elevation_after_masking')
#output--req_value_after_masking=[-- ,-0.017992424972 ,--, -0.017573278548, -0.017393141436]
# since after masking nan converted to --
# so numpy is not accepting the -- value while doing interpolation .

class Estimation():
    def __init__(self, datax, datay, dataz):
        self.x = datax
        self.y = datay
        self.v = dataz

    def estimate(self, x, y, using='ISD'):
        """
        Estimate point at coordinate x,y based on the input data for this
        class.
        """
        if using == 'ISD':
            return self._isd(x, y)

    def _isd(self, x, y):
        d = np.sqrt((x - self.x) ** 2 + (y - self.y) ** 2)
        if d.min() > 0:
            v = np.sum(self.v * (1 / d ** 2) / np.sum(1 / d ** 2))
            return v
        else:
            return self.v[d.argmin()]


print("x1:[:5]", x1[:5])
print("y1:[:5]", y1[:5])
print("req_elevation:[:5]", req_elevation[:5])

e = Estimation(x1, y1, req_elevation)

# Below newZ is shown as error line
newZ = [e.estimate(parms1[i], parms2[i]) for i in range(len(parms1))]
```

```
  File "/home/cartopy/feb20_adcirc_plot.py", line 265, in run
    newZ = [e.estimate(parms1[i], parms2[i]) for i in range(len(parms1))]
  File "/home/cartopy/feb20_adcirc_plot.py", line 265, in <listcomp>
    newZ = [e.estimate(parms1[i], parms2[i]) for i in range(len(parms1))]
  File "/home/cartopy/feb20_adcirc_plot.py", line 228, in estimate
    return self._isd(x, y)
  File "/home/cartopy/feb20_adcirc_plot.py", line 233, in _isd
    v = np.sum(self.v * (1 / d ** 2) / np.sum(1 / d ** 2))
  File "/home/cartopy/feb20_adcirc_plot.py", line 4084, in __mul__
    return multiply(self, other)
  File "/home/cartopy/feb20_adcirc_plot.py", line 1016, in __call__
    result = self.f(da, db, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'SingleBlockManager'**
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any help on this question ?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no `SingleBlockManager` in numpy, and the backtrace lines mention the same source file as your other code. I think this question cannot really be answered without knowing what's that.

Comment: Hi,
if you run the same above code you will get the same error typeerror , 
Thank you.

Comment: @sameer_nubia Running the above code gives me: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list'` on `d = np.sqrt((x - self.x) ** 2 + (y - self.y) ** 2)`. self.x and self.y are lists and x and y given in estimate function are floats.

Comment: I think by solving **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list' on d = np.sqrt((x - self.x) ** 2 + (y - self.y)**
How to solve this TypeError ?
My problem will be solved .

Comment: The `float - list` error is there because in the sqrt function listed by @ROAR, x is a single floating point number and self.x is a list (the x1 list on the second line). You can't subtract a list from a float, but you can subtract a numpy array from a float. Wrap `np.array()` around your x1 and y1 and it will work. Additionally, I think your "SingleBlockManager" problem came because you fed different x1 and y1 in your code than you did here on StackOverflow. Make sure they are numpy arrays and you will be fine.

Comment: @TomNorway , Thanks alot , making np.array(x1) made my script working.